# Simple Android App Crashing

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm following the Starting Another Activity tutorial on the Android Developer website but, every time I try to run my app it crashes.  I have been unable to find my error but it always crashes after I hit the submit button. I'm very new to this and have no idea what's wrong.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myFirstApp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//responds to user clicking button
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.example.myfirstapp", "com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity");
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_send"
android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
//import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.LayoutInflater;
//import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView= new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);
    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

and activity_display_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView android="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat

```
08-26 17:53:31.124: D/gralloc_goldfish(1278): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-26 17:53:49.884: I/Choreographer(1278): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be       doing too much work on its main thread.
08-26 17:53:53.164: D/AndroidRuntime(1278): Shutting down VM
08-26 17:53:53.164: W/dalvikvm(1278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a36ba8)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1278
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     ... 11 more
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:46)
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please, post your logcat.

Comment: I have added the logcat

Comment: So... do you have an Activity called DisplayMessageActivity.java in your Android project? And if so, is it declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I believe I declared it at the bottom of the manifest file which is included in my post. I'm not positive that I did it correctly though because I am new to this. And yes I have the activity all my files are in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add the 2nd activity to your manifest.  Most common mistake ;)

Yep, there's the proof:

```
08-26 17:53:53.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1278): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Get rid of the fully qualified name and use .DisplayMessageActivity instead.

Comment: <activity
        android:name="com.example.myFirstApp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myFirstApp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>                                                         I had this in the manifest. Is it not done properly?

Comment: Thank you by getting rid of the fully qualified name the app worked. Can you explain to me why that made a difference?

Comment: The manifest reads your package name and appends what you're putting in for the path to your activity.  So, if you had your packages broken out more you could do something like ".ui.activities.DisplayMessageActivity" and that would be appended to "com.example.myFirstApp".